# JSON templating engine

Tags: javascript, json, templates

Is there any JSON templating engine? I'm looking for something like this...

```
var template = {
  'sts': '%data1.sts%',
  'msg': '%data2.msg%'
};

var data1 = {
  'sts': 200
};

var data2 = {
  'msg': 'Hi!'
};

// render(template, [data sources]);
var response = render(template, [data1, data2]);

console.log(response);
```

Output

```
{
  'sts': 200,
  'msg': 'Hi!'
}
```

Thanks for reply!

Comment: For anyone coming to this: checkout JSONNET - https://jsonnet.org

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Keep it simple.

```
function template(data) {

  var object = {
    'sts': data[0].sts,
    'msg': data[1].msg
  };

  return object;

}
```

Comment: He was asking for a templating system, not for a programmatic way to achieve the same,

Comment: @SimonePontiggia Javascript is already a templating system for JSON

Comment: This is not an accepted answer for people who are trying to separate view and controller logic. JSON documents obviously can have a parsable syntax like HTML and many other documents to achieve MVC or similar software design patterns.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) templating. It appears to be what you are after.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can use two data sources with Mustache... Can I?

Comment: Can you use `{{ }}` template markers in a json and still be able to read it?

Comment: Updated link to mustache site: https://mustache.github.io

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there exists a JSON templating engine.  I don't know what you need, but json-templater is an option.

template.json:

```
{
  "magic_key_{{magic}}": {
    "key": "interpolation is nice {{value}}"
  }
}
```

======== Your code that uses the template ========

```
var object = require('json-templater/object');
var result = object(
  require('./template.json'),
  { magic: 'key', value: 'value' }
);

console.log(result);

/* should look something like this: 
{
  magic_key_key: {
    key: 'interpolation is nice value'
  }
}
*/
```

Comment: is that the one : https://github.com/lightsofapollo/json-templater ?

Comment: It's been a while, but I believe that's the one.

Answer (score 1):

If you go from JSON to JSON, you can stay with Javascript, and just reverse the order of assignments:

```
var data1 = {
  sts: 200
};

var data2 = {
  msg: 'Hi!'
};

var template = {
  sts: data1.sts,
  msg: data2.msg
};

console.log( JSON.stringify(template) ); //--> {"sts":200,"msg":"Hi!"}
```

`JSON.stringify` is available on most modern browsers as a native object and methode. If not you can use [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)

But if you need a template engine to convert JSON to HTML, you can have a look at [pure.js](http://beebole.com/pure)