# jQuery populate form from json

Tags: jquery, json, forms

I'm clearly missing something about jquery... I'm trying to populate a form that is inside a jQueryUI dialog box.
I'm getting the JSON data just fine, but it escapes me how I reference the data and set the value of the form fields...

You will see THREE attempts below - the last one is the one almost everyone says to use - but the form remains BLANK...
What am I missing?????

```
$( '#companies' ).on( 'click', '.uLink' , function( event ) {
    // set ID
    var xid = $( this ).data( 'identity' );
    // get record
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'm/company_edit.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { id: xid },
        success: function ( data ) {
            // display dialog
            $( '#company-form-container' ).dialog( 'open' );

            /* ATTEMPT #1 - with a variant on 'name' - form remains blank
            // populate form
            $( '#companyid' ).val( value.id );
            $( '#name' ).val( 'test' + value.name );
            $( '#address1' ).val( value.address1 );
            $( '#address2' ).val( value.address2 );
            $( '#city' ).val( value.city );
            $( '#state' ).val( value.state );
            $( '#postalcode' ).val( value.postalcode );
            $( '#phone' ).val( value.phone );
            $( '#contact' ).val( value.contat );
            $( '#email' ).val( value.email );
            */

            /* ATTEMPT #2 - supposed to make some accommodation for field type...
                            Make assumption that fields are named same as JSON fields, and the you only
                            want to use the data value in that one spot...*/
                           /*
            var frm = '#company-form';
            $.each(data, function( key, value ){
                var $ctrl = $( '[name='+key+']', frm );
                switch( $ctrl.attr( "type" ) )  {  
                    case "text" :   
                    case "hidden":  
                    case "textarea":  
                    $ctrl.val(value);   
                    break;   
                    case "radio" : case "checkbox":   
                    $ctrl.each(function(){ if($(this).attr('value') == value) {  $(this).attr("checked",value); } });
                    break;  
                }  
            });  
            */

            // attempt 3 - still no go
            $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
                $( '#' + key ).val( value ); 
               });
```

/*
                               // attempt suggested below - no changes...
                                var c =  jQuery.parseJSON( data );

```
            // populate form
            $( '#companyid' ).val( c.id );
            $( '#name' ).val( c.name );
```

*/

```
        },

        error: function () {    
            // there's an error
            $( '#message' ).html( '<p>There was a problem on the server... </p>' );
            $( '#message' ).removeClass( 'hidden' ).addClass( 'message' );
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Sample of JSON data

```
[{"id":"3", "name":"Sub Customer B", "address1":"232 road", "address2":"", "city":"Galatan ", "state":"TN", "phone":"", "email":""}]
```

and this is the HTML Form

```
<!-- the form -->
<div id="company-form-container" title="Create New Company">
<p class="validateTips">* fields are required.</p> 
<form id="company-form" >
<fieldset>

    <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" id="customer_id" value="" />

    <label for="name">name<sup>*</sup> <span class="fieldhint"></span></label> <br/>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" 
           size="50" maxlength="100" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /><br/>

    <label for="address1">address1 <span class="fieldhint"></span></label> <br/>
    <input type="text" name="address1" id="address1" 
           size="20" maxlength="100" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /><br/>

    <label for="address2">address2 <span class="fieldhint"></span></label> <br/>
    <input type="text" name="address2" id="address2" 
           size="10" maxlength="50" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /><br/>

    <label for="city">city <span class="fieldhint"></span></label> <br/>
    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" 
           size="20" maxlength="50" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /><br/>

    <label for="state">state <span class="fieldhint"></span></label> <br/>
    <input type="text" name="state" id="state" 
           size="5" maxlength="3" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /><br/>

    <label for="postalcode">postal code <span class="fieldhint"></span></label> <br/>
    <input type="text" name="postalcode" id="postalcode" 
           size="20" maxlength="15" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /><br/>

    <label for="phone">phone <span class="fieldhint"></span></label> <br/>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" 
           size="20" maxlength="20" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /><br/>

    <label for="contact">contact <span class="fieldhint"></span></label> <br/>
    <input type="text" name="contact" id="contact" 
           size="20" maxlength="50" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /><br/>

    <label for="email">email <span class="fieldhint"></span></label> <br/>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" 
           size="20" maxlength="100" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /><br/>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Can we see the contents of `data`?

Comment: You need to show more... the contents of `data`/`result` and your HTML that it is referring to. Your keys need to match up with actual IDs of the elements

Comment: JSON data added...
HTML form added...

Answer (score 1):

myopic coding... brought on by too many little things...

the issue was that the form had a field "customer_id" but the JSON was feeding "id"...

```
$.each( data, function( key, value ) {
    $( '#' + key ).val( value ); 
});
```

THIS code did indeed work, once I corrected this error - of course I had to break it out into a separate page and isolate each step in order to see that - however it's give me a little better insight.

Thx for the help

Answer (score 0):

Success function is returning json data into 'data' variable, while you are using 'result' variable in your 3rd attempt.

So, Changing "success: function ( data )" line into "success: function ( result )" maybe solve your problem.

**EDIT**

Check Using,

```
var c = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
$( '#companyid' ).val( c['id'] );
$( '#name' ).val( c['name'] );
```

Comment: thx user - been looking at it too long. changed that... NO DIFFERENCE in behavior

Answer (score 0):

use [jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to decode the json encoded data in the method 1. Make sure that you do send json encoded data from your `company_edit.php`

## For Your Information

I guess it would be perfect if you can use a Javascript template engine which will do the trick for you. Try one of these with the method one.

[Good Javascript template engine to work with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929111/good-javascript-template-engine-to-work-with-json)

[JSON templating engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580632/json-templating-engine)

[What Javascript Template Engines you recommend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788611/what-javascript-template-engines-you-recommend)

http://www.jquery4u.com/javascript/10-javascript-jquery-templates-engines/

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://github.com/corinis/jsForm to fill the form fields with the json (and back again)